# The integral of the product of three Meijer-G-functions

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

Is there any expression for the integral of the product of three Meijer-G-functions, where the domain of integration is $[0,1]$?

Comment: Perhaps I'll be proven wrong, but this question seems to me too general to be answered. Do you have a specific integral in mind? And, If I may ask, where does the question come from?